# how do i disable all windows 7 shortcuts?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

No matter what program I'm in, word, the internet, outlook, etc., I'm getting popup windows (print, new window, etc.) or edits just by hitting a key.   I'm fairly certain I'm not hitting control or alt first but they constantly popup.  I've never had a keyboard do this before.  I actually took a computer back because it was doing that and now the second computer does the same thing.

How do I turn off all shortcut keys in Windows 7 so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your keyboard is faulty and/or a key is stuck.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you have Sticky Keys enabled.  To disable Sticky Keys:

- Click Start.
- Select Control Panel
- Click the Ease of Access heading.
- Click “Change how your keyboard works”
- Remove the check mark from the box next to “Turn on Sticky Keys” (if it’s checked).

Comment: You missed out "Select Control Panel" at step 2

Comment: @ChrisF - I edited it in.

Comment: @Nifle - I thought I'd give the OP the chance